# Node + Gulp - Have to save files two times to see changes in browser

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

Could you please point me in the right direction to solve this inconsistence?

I'm working in a new project using **Node, gulp and a list of gulp's plugins**.
Everytime I do Ctrl + S the browser does reload but I don't see the changes applied so I need to Ctrl + S again to see them. This second time the browser reloads again displaying the changes.

This is happening with **any of my html, scss or js files** under my source directory.

I'm working on Windows 10 using Visual Studio Code and everything works fine except for this.

My gulpfile.js content is the following:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var inject = require('gulp-inject');
    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
    var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
    var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

    gulp.task('styles', function(){
      var injectFiles = gulp.src(['!src/styles/main.scss', 'src/styles/*.scss'], {read: false});
      var injectGlobalFiles = gulp.src('src/global/*.scss', {read: false});

     function transformFilepath(filepath) {
        return '@import "' + filepath + '";';
      }

      var injectFilesOptions = {
        transform: transformFilepath,
        starttag: '// inject:app',
        endtag: '// endinject',
        addRootSlash: false
      };

      var injectGlobalOptions = {
        transform: transformFilepath,
        starttag: '// inject:global',
        endtag: '// endinject',
        addRootSlash: false
      };

      return gulp.src('src/styles/main.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(wiredep())
        .pipe(inject(injectGlobalFiles, injectGlobalOptions))
        .pipe(inject(injectFiles, injectFilesOptions))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'));
    });

    gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {  
      browserSync.init(["styles/*.css", "js/*.js","index.html"], {
          server: {
              baseDir: "dist"
          }
      });
    });

    gulp.task('html', ['styles'], function(){
      var injectFiles = gulp.src('src/styles/*.scss', {read: false});
      var injectOptions = {
        addRootSlash: false,
        ignorePath: ['src', 'dist']
      };

      return gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(inject(injectFiles, injectOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });

    gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
      gulp.src('src/assets/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg}')
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(imagemin())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets'));
    });

    gulp.task('uglify', function() {
      gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
          .pipe(uglify())
          .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
    });

    gulp.task('sass', function() {
      gulp.src('src/styles/*.scss')
          .pipe(plumber())
          .pipe(sass())
          .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles/'));
    });

    gulp.task('watch', function() {
      gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['uglify']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
      gulp.watch('src/styles/*.scss', ['sass']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
      gulp.watch('src/assets/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg}', ['imagemin']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
      gulp.watch('src/index.html', ['html']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    });



gulp.task('default', ['html', 'sass','imagemin', 'uglify', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

**Thank you and have a good one.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

 gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['uglify']).on('change', browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
  gulp.watch('src/styles/*.scss', ['sass']).on('change', browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
  gulp.watch('src/assets/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg}', ['imagemin']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('src/index.html', ['html']).on('change', browserSync.reload());
});
```

If that doesn't help, I would move the reload calls to the end of each task like this :

```
.pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
```

Hope this helps.

**[EDIT]**

Change to this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['uglify']);
  gulp.watch('src/styles/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('src/assets/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg}', ['imagemin']);
  gulp.watch('src/index.html', ['html']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/assets/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg}')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets'));
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
});

gulp.task('uglify', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles/'));
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
});
```

The other parts of your gulpfile don't change.  Except do make the previously suggested change:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
```

Comment: Hello @Mark, thanks for your answer. I'm afraid that your first option didn't work. I'm receiving the following:


TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\full_path\gulpfile.js:92:41)

The line 92 says: gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['uglify']).on('change', browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));

it's the first one with your suggested code.

Now, could you please explain me your second option? I think I didn't get it right. What do you mean?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for your reply. It's working now in some way. Now the process saves the changes at the first Save, but it doesn't reload the browsers. I had to do it manually. Can you see where could be the problem? Also, the error message is still there -> "listener" argument must be a function.
Thanks for your knowledge and patience too.

Comment: I made a small change to the html watch call.  See if that makes any difference.  On what line is that error message referring to?

Comment: Hey Mark, your solution worked pretty well. Sorry about the super delay on the response and thank you very much!

Comment: No problem.  If you think it was helpful, please accept the answer as correct so others will know without having to read all the comments.  Thank you.